# Setting JAVA_OPTS in windows using command prompt

Tags: java, java-opts

I am running the java program on windows server 2012, I want to set the JAVA_OPTS variable and use it, here is how I am doing it:

Open a command prompt in the bin of jdk where it is installed ,and executing  the following command :

```
$set JAVA_OPTS = “-Xdebug , server=y”
```

Then in the next line in the command prompt only , when I try to run

```
$java $JAVA_OPTS –cp .Server
```

(where Server is the name of the java program), I get an error saying that:
Could not find or load assembly $JAVA_OPTS. Please let me know what mistake I am doing here. I am not using IDE for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on windows you have to set the variable like:

```
set JAVA_OPTS = “-Xdebug , server=y”
```

and use it this way

```
java %JAVA_OPTS% –cp .Server
```

Comment: While running the program, It gives "Could not load main class Ucp"

Comment: @user1907849 is the main method in class Ucp?

Comment: @user1907849 you hae to add the mainclass at the end of your statement. If Server is your mainclass you have to use this command: `java %JAVA_OPTS% –cp .Server Server`. If your class has a packagename you have to enter it before the second Server.

Comment: I Found the mistake I was doing , the correct command is java %JAVA_OPTS% –cp . Server,        there is space between . and Server

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses "%JAVA_OPTS% rather than "$JAVA_OPTS" which is UNIX/LINUX.
You can check if the environment is updated with JAVA_OPTS by echoing that:
echo %JAVA_OPTS%.